Don't start GitLab pipeline on specific commit title
I have a GitLab Pipeline that does:

Build the software
Deploy the software
Add a git tag
Create a changelog, commit it, and push it

After the push of the changelog, I don't want the pipeline to run again. That's why I added this rule:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^docs:\ Changelog\ updated\ for\ release\s/
      when: never

to the workflow. It should match commit titles like
docs: Changelog updated for release 1.2.4.211

However a subsequent pipeline does always run:

Why is this workflow rule not prohibiting the run? It seems that the regex is not catching the title.
This is the complete configuration of the pipeline:
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - addtags
  - addchangelog

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^docs:\ Changelog\ updated\ for\ release\s/
      when: never

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "This job builds something"
  rules:
    - when: always

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

addtags:
  image: public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node
  script:
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - VERSION_PACKAGE_JSON=$(npm pkg get version --workspaces=false | tr -d \").$CI_PIPELINE_IID
    - git tag $VERSION_PACKAGE_JSON
    - git push
      https://CI_AUTOMATION:${CI_AUTOMATION_GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git
      $VERSION_PACKAGE_JSON
      HEAD:main
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  stage: addtags

addchangelog:
  image: public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node
  script:
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - git pull --tags origin main
    - git tag
    - npx --yes auto-changelog --tag-pattern .+
    - git add CHANGELOG.md
    - LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 )
    - "git commit -m \"docs: Changelog updated for release ${LATEST_TAG}\""
    - git push
      https://CI_AUTOMATION:${CI_AUTOMATION_GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git
      HEAD:main
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  stage: addchangelog

Why do I not use [ci skip] in the commit message? Because that creates an empty pipeline:


You could try just adding [ci skip] to the commit message instead and use the automatic pipeline skipping that that enables https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#skip-a-pipeline

Or using git push -o ci.skip https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/commit.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd

Have you checked to see if replacing $CI_COMMIT_TITLE with $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE works?

When I try with a rule with - if $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^docs:\ Changelog\ updated\ for\ release\s/ when: never, the GitLab CI seems to work as expected and not create a pipeline if the commit message contains that string.

Do you know what gitlab version and gitlab-runner version is being used?

I managed to fix it myself, but thank you for the hints @MattPitkin

I managed to fix it. I think there were two errors:

The rule preventing the duplicate pipeline was not first. On of the other rules evaluated to true before, so the duplicate pipeline was created. This is the right order:

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^docs:\ Changelog\ updated\ for\ release\s/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never


The regex to match the commit title was at the end set to match a space. However the commit title had a version number at the end. This is the correct regex:

    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^docs:\ Changelog\ updated\ for\ release\ .*/
      when: never

